# How to auto display button if condition in PHP is true?

Tags: php, jquery

I want to auto display (without refreshing the page) button if, `IF` condition in `PHP` is true.

I tried:

```
<?php if($diffex >= "90"){  ?>
      <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit" style="float:right;" name="btn-resend">
         Resend OTP
      </button>
<?php }  ?>
```

But the above code needs the page to be refreshed and I want it without refreshing it.

My `$diffex` is calculated as under:

```
<?php
$eotd="";
$otd="";
if(isset($_GET['od'])){
    $eotd = $_GET['od'];
    $otd = base64_decode($eotd);
}
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
$cdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s ', time());
$scdate = strtotime($cdate);
$dscdate = base64_encode($cdate);
$deotd = strtotime($otd);
$diffex = $scdate - $deotd;
?>
```

**Actually, I need this for displaying `Resend Option` if `the current time` is greater than the time in `URL` by `90s`**

Comment: you have to make your network call asynchronous from frontend using ajax and get result from your php script and toggle the class of your button.

Comment: @RamaKrishna Can you please update my code with the same..

Comment: Slight nitpick here: the quotes around `90` aren't necessary. Doing so requires PHP to convert it to a numeric value anyway.

Comment: I think you don't need php code for your requirement and .You can do only with javascript. to check the current time is greater than the time.

Comment: @scarletwitch How to do so, if I go with: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46948273/8835762, then have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46947259/how-to-auto-display-button-if-condition-in-php-is-true?noredirect=1#comment80844542_46948273 with my updated question.

Answer (score 2):

As you've already noted, there is no way to do this in server-side in PHP. You'll need JavaScript running on the client side to update the DOM whenever the button should be displayed or hidden.

At the simplest level, to do what you're asking, you'll probably end up sending AJAX requests to a PHP script that will respond to your client-side JavaScript in JSON. Once you have that data, you can update the view from there.

**Example:**

*check_diffex.php*

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

// You would calculate a real value here

echo json_encode([
  'diffex' => 101
]);
```

---

*JavaScript*

```
var checkState = function(){
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/check_diffex.php'
  }).done(function(data){
    var button = jQuery("#myButton");
    if(data.diffex >= 90) {
      button.show();
    } else {
      button.hide();
    }
  });

}

checkState();
setInterval(checkState, 10);
```

The tricky part with something like native JavaScript and jQuery is deciding how to structure your code that checks that `diffex >= 90` with the rest of your application. A lot of quick and dirty implementations will quickly turn into a headache, even for the simplest of "if this, then that" checks.

---

These days, the most accessible and maintainable way to do what you're asking is to adopt a Single Page Application (SPA) framework, such as:

- [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/)
- [Angular](https://angularjs.org/)
- [React](https://reactjs.org/)

I highly recommend you take a look at Vue, as you can integrate it into existing projects without having to rewrite the entire front-end.

Comment: How can I do it with `PHP` and `jquery`?

Comment: @MKJ - Example added. This is something you should get in the habit of Googling, though. This very topic has probably been covered hundreds of times.

Comment: @MKJ - You'll need to adapt the example to your application - for instance, output `diffex` based on your actual data, then assign and use a proper ID on your HTML button. `<button id="bleh">` -> `jQuery('#bleh');`

Comment: Can I write `check_diffex.php` code on the same page where the button is to be displayed?

Comment: Ideally, no. You want to separate AJAX requests from server-side view rendering entirely. The main reason is that communication via AJAX should be as quick and simple as possible; a quick "question" to the server, and a data response that can be acted on via JavaScript without refreshing the page.

Comment: I have edited the question, which will help you in understanding my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

php script can be executed on server only so without refresh, you can not get php code executed.
So when you get the page first time, `$diffex` will have some value and based on it, you can either get the button on page or not.

Now, until you refresh the page, `$diffex` variable will not get updated with new value (if changed).

So you should either workout using javascript or jQuery.

Comment: google about it my friend. You will get many example code. It would be a broad to answer to guide you for JS or Jquery.

Comment: @MKJ do you know ajax?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay I tried, but end up with no solution as per my request..