# Display Last userID in php from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to echo last `userID` stored in `MySQL`. But it is not shown. No error is displayed.

I tried:

```
$stmti = $reg_user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users");
    $rowi = $stmti->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $tf = $rowi['userID'];
echo $tf;
```

Comment: Try changing your SQL statement to SELECT MAX(userID) as userID FROM tbl_users

Comment: @jeff I have 10 tables in the database, so how to set from which table it should take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
$sth = $reg_user->prepare("SELECT MAX(userID) as userID FROM tbl_users");
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$tf= ($result['userID']);
echo $tf;
```

Comment: I have 10 tables in the database, so how to set from which table it should take?

Comment: what is the output of $rowi  ? try var_dump($rowi );

Comment: C:\wamp64\www\dcs\signup.php:31:null

Comment: It is coming as : `Array ( [userID] => 13 )`

Comment: isn't it the id you want to get? i edited again to get final answer .Try that out.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Do you how to solve https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46947259/how-to-auto-display-button-if-condition-in-php-is-true ?

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46948273/8835762 partially solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

/* NOTE: This works only with mysqli
   change the parameters "host","username","password","db_name" with your 
   own ones
 */

```
$link = mysqli_connect("host","username","password","db_name");
$query = "  SELECT *
            FROM tbl_users";

$rows = array();
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
    $rows[] = $row;
$lastID = 0;
for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($rows) ; $i++)
     $lastID = $i;
echo $rows[$lastID]["userID"];
```